# How call WCF service from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service in folder "Services":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace Application.Services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ScriptService]    
    public class ProductTypeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebMethod]
        public string LoadMainGridProductType(string test)
        {
            return "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

and on page I try to call this service method from javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = "test";    
    Application.Services.ProductTypeService.LoadMainGridProductType(counter, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);
});
```

on page I also make conect to this service and javascript files:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/ProductType.js" />
            </Scripts>
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/ProductTypeService.svc" />        
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

but code fails on

```
Application.Services.ProductTypeService.LoadMainGridProductType(counter, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);
```

Error : Error of implementation of Microsoft Jscript: "Application" is not certain.
How fix this???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How get namespace on javascript in asp,net web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182501/how-get-namespace-on-javascript-in-asp-net-web)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check to see if the WCF service is working correctly by navigating directly to it, e.g. http://localhost:(port-number)/Services/ProductTypeService.svc

I suspect that this wont work and give you some errors.

Secondly, check to make sure that the jsdebug javascript file has been generated and is included in the scripts loaded with the application.

Another person asked a similar question earlier.
[How get namespace on javascript in asp.net web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182501/how-get-namespace-on-javascript-in-asp-net-web/8182614#comment10051567_8182614)