# How get namespace on javascript in asp.net web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var counter = "test";
            WebApplication1.Service1.DoWork(counter, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);
        });
        function ResultLoadMainGridProductType() {


        }
        function ErrorLoadMainGridProductType() { 


        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">            
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service1.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code fails on `WebApplication1.Service1.DoWork(counter, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);`
Error: Error of implementation of Microsoft Jscript: "WebApplication1" is not certain.
WebApplication1 - the namespace... then I watch it it undefined on javascript code working.
How make it be there??

Comment: Is `WebApplication1.Service1.DoWork` a serverside method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var counter = "test";
    var service1 = new WebApplication1.Service1();
    service1.DoWork(counter, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);
});
```

Also check to make sure that the javascript file `jsdebug` is in your loaded scripts.

Comment: the same error on line: var service1 = new WebApplication1.Service1()

Comment: Is jsdebug present? What happens when you navigate directly to the WCF Service? e.g. http://localhost:(portnumber)/Service1.svc ?